# Multiple tables is not working on android

Tags: android, dao, android-sqlite

i've searched on web to solve my problem, but none of the solutions i found work for me, so that is my problem.

I have a dao:

```
public class AqntCategoryDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


public static abstract class AqntCategoryEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TAG = "tag";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = "status";
}

//globals
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AquiNaoTemPlaces.db";

public static String[] columns = {
    AqntCategoryEntry._ID,
    AqntCategoryEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,
    AqntCategoryEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TAG,
    AqntCategoryEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS
    };

public AqntCategoryDAO(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    StringBuffer sql_create = new StringBuffer();
    sql_create.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+AqntCategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    sql_create.append("( ");
        sql_create.append(AqntCategoryEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntCategoryEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME+" TEXT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntCategoryEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TAG+" TEXT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntCategoryEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS+" INTEGER");
    sql_create.append(" )");
    Log.i("SQL: ",sql_create.toString());
    db.execSQL(sql_create.toString());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AqntCategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
...
```

and:

```
public class AqntPlacesDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


public static abstract class AqntPlacesEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "places";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LATITUDEE6 = "latitudeE6";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDEE6 = "longitudeE6";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RATE = "rate";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = "status";
}

//globals
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AquiNaoTemPlaces.db";

public static String[] columns = {
    AqntPlacesEntry._ID,
    AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,
    AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LATITUDEE6,
    AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDEE6,
    AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_RATE,
    AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS
    };

public AqntPlacesDAO(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    StringBuffer sql_create = new StringBuffer();
    sql_create.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+AqntPlacesEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    sql_create.append("( ");
        sql_create.append(AqntPlacesEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME+" TEXT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LATITUDEE6+" TEXT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDEE6+" TEXT,");
        sql_create.append(AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_RATE+" REAL,");
        sql_create.append(AqntPlacesEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS+" INTEGER");
    sql_create.append(" )");
    Log.i("SQL: ",sql_create.toString());
    db.execSQL(sql_create.toString());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF `EXISTS` " + AqntPlacesEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
...
```

and when i try to

```
AqntPlacesDAO daoPlace = new AqntPlacesDAO(context);
AqntCategoryDAO catAuxDAO = new AqntCategoryDAO(context);

List<AqntPlaces> places = daoPlace.getPlaces();
List<AqntCategory> catss = catAuxDAO.getCategories();
daoPlace.close();
catAuxDAO.close();
```

it creates just the fist one and the other show me the error:

```
02-19 22:51:29.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9336): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, tag, status FROM category
```

but if I run just one DAO, it works.

Somebody knows what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing your problems because `onCreate()` is called *only when the database file does not exist*.

Both your DAOs share the database file `AquiNaoTemPlaces.db`, but only the first one actually used will cause its `onCreate()` method to be called. In your case it's "places" DAO - it will be initialized under the hood in this line:

```
List<AqntPlaces> places = daoPlace.getPlaces();
```

After that the database file will be initialized by the `AqntPlacesDAO.onCreate()` method. When the VM executes the line:

```
List<AqntCategory> catss = catAuxDAO.getCategories();
```

the database file will already exist and be initialized, so the `AqntCategoryDAO.onCreate()` *will not* be called.

The solution is to use *one* `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass (let's call it `Helper`) per database file. Of course you can then subclass `Helper` for each of your logical DAOs - the design is up to you. The key here is that the `Helper.onCreate()`/`onUpgrade()` should create/modify *all* tables stored in the underlying database.